# Почему неверный порядок при распаковке кортежа получается

Tags: python, структуры

Не совсем получается одна задача на Питон.

С одного англоязычниного задачника по Питон,
на английском:

> Your mission here is to create a function that gets an tuple  and
>   returns a tuple with 3 elements - first, third and second  to the last
>   for the given tuple

```
Input: A tuple, at least 3 elements long.

Output: A tuple.

Example:

easy_unpack((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9)) == (1, 3, 7)

easy_unpack((1, 1, 1, 1)) == (1, 1, 1)

easy_unpack((6, 3, 7)) == (6, 7, 3).
```

Перевожу:наша задача -создать функцию
которая принимает кортеж и возврощает кортеж с
3 мя элементами-1-м,3-им и 2-ым справа.
Не проходит 3 й assert:

```
def easy_unpack(elements):
    """
        returns a tuple with 3 elements - first, third and second to the last
    """
    # your code here
    l=list() 
    for j,i in enumerate(elements):
        if j==0:
            l.append(i)
        if j==2:
            l.append(i)
        if j==len(elements)-2:
            l.append(i)

    return tuple(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert easy_unpack((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9))== (1, 3, 7)

    assert easy_unpack((1, 1, 1, 1))== (1, 1, 1)

    assert easy_unpack((6, 3, 7))== (6, 7, 3),easy_unpack((6, 3, 7))
    #--->assert easy_unpack((6, 3, 7))== (6, 7, 3),easy_unpack((6, 3, 7))
    #--->AssertionError: (6, 3, 7)    
    print('Done! Go Check!')
```

Comment: Мб потому что у вас лишний easy_unpack в конце?

Comment: хммм, а зачем так сложно? `def easy_unpack(tup): return tup[0], tup[2], tup[-2]`

Comment: @MaxU да так работает)

Comment: @BogdanBida  easy_unpack в конце,это что бы видеть что assert выдает,это ответ моей функции,хотя неправильный был.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка у вас из-за неверного порядка элементов. Нужно "первый", "третий", "второй с конца".

У вас "второй с конца" в последнем примере имеет индекс в кортеже на входе меньше чем "третий" поэтому он раньше в список добавляется, поэтому вы неверно возвращаете: "первый","второй с конца", "третий" `(6,3,7)` вместо `(6,7,3)`.

```
def easy_unpack(L):
    return L[0], L[2], L[-2]
```

Пример:

```
>>> easy_unpack((1, 2, 3))
(1, 3, 2)
```